# How can I stop a system ftplugin file from overriding the keybindings from a plugin I manage via vim-plug?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-vim-plug

I am using the [merlin](https://github.com/the-lambda-church/merlin) plugin for Ocaml and right now I set the runtimepath by hand, as per their installation instructions:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugins')
  "other plugins go here...
call plug#end()

set rtp+=/home/hugo/.opam/4.02.3/share/merlin/vim
```

I want to change this so that merlin is managed by vim-plug for consistency and because of vim-plug's lazy-loading feature. I tried doing the following but now my ocaml keybindings are broken:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugins')
  "other plugins go here...

  Plug '/home/hugo/.opam/4.02.3/share/merlin/vim'
call plug#end()
```

Apparently, there is an `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/ocaml.vim` file in my system that overrides some of the keybindings that are automatically defined by merlin. When I was setting the runtimepath by hand the merlin directory appeared last in the runtimepath list (as seen via `:echo &rtp`), which seemingly causes merlin to load last but when I use vim-plug the merlin dir shows up before `/usr/share/vim/vim74` and the keybinds from the system file have priority.

What is the best way to solve this conflict? Should I look for a way to disable the unwanted ftplugin file that comes installed in my system? Should I redefine all the broken keybindings by hand? Or is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the top of $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/ocaml.vim -- you'll see some lines that say:

```
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
  finish
endif
```

So, put in your personal

```
$HOME/.vim/ftplugin/ocaml.vim
```

the line

```
let b:did_ftplugin= 1
```

This will effectively prevent the system ocaml plugin from loading.